# Error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I'm trying to upload the multipart file which has xml content, the xml data will be parse one by one and stored in the database.

**Sample XML Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
     <Copyright>
          <applicationno>1641/2001</applicationno>
          <applicationdate>11/15/2001 12:00:00 AM</applicationdate>
          <TitleEnglish>DURA PLUS</TitleEnglish>
          <applicantname>FARMIGEA PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD.</applicantname>
          <class>ARTISTIC WORK</class>
          <City>LAHORE</City>
          <Country>PAKISTAN</Country>
          <status>Application Registered</status>
     </Copyright>
     <Copyright>
          <applicationno>1644/2001</applicationno>
          <applicationdate>11/15/2001 12:00:00 AM</applicationdate>
          <TitleEnglish>OCUGEL FARMIGEA</TitleEnglish>
          <applicantname>FARMIGEA PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD.</applicantname>
          <class>ARTISTIC WORK</class>
          <City>LAHORE</City>
          <Country>PAKISTAN</Country>
          <status>Application Registered</status>
     </Copyright>
<Table>
```

**API**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/ipo" name="IPOSearch" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property expression="//mediate/ipo" name="Table" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="base64Decode(get-property('Table'))" name="DecodeTable" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <root>$1</root>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('DecodeTable')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <foreach expression="//Table/Copyright" id="foreach_copyright">
                <sequence>
                    <dbreport>
                        <connection>
                            <pool>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://XXXXXX:5432/secpleapdev?currentSchema=secpleap</url>
                                <user>postgres</user>
                                <password>root</password>
                            </pool>
                        </connection>
                        <statement>
                            <sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO secpleap.ipo_copyright
(application_no, application_date, title_english, applicant_name, class_name, city, country, status)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
]]></sql>
                            <parameter expression="//applicationno" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//applicationdate" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//TitleEnglish" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//applicantname" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//class" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//City" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//Country" type="VARCHAR" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                            <parameter expression="//status" type="VARCHAR"/>
                        </statement>
                    </dbreport>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="add" value="Records added!!!!"/>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
    "status" : "Records added",&#xd;
    &#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>&#xd;
{&#xd;
    "status" : "Failure",&#xd;
    "records" : "0"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Error**

```
[2022-12-28 18:39:52,890] ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:IPOSearch} com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62] org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:132)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:111)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:477)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcess(AbstractApiHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:376)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:435)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,62]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readPIPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:3940)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2816)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 29 more
```

**Question**

1. I've converted base64 encoded data but before looping when I'm
   generating a new `payload`, its giving me the error which is mentioned
   above. Any resolution to that?
2. If lets say I don't use `payload factory` before `foreach`
   mediator, how could I use `DecodeTable` property values as expression
   of `foreach` mediator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to include the [XML Declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>`) in the Payload which is incorrect.

Inorder to resolve the issue, instead of a `type="STRING"` property try using an `type="OM"` property. Then the XML will be parsed correctly and you will have an XML node tree that you can easily traverse. Then use that in your Payloadfactory.

```xml
<property expression="base64Decode(get-property('Table'))" name="DecodeTable" scope="default" type="OM"/>
```